# Control height of Flex Box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning how to use the flex box model in HTML5 and came across the problem of not being able to control the height of my boxes in this code, which I shortened as much as possible.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Welcome to my site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mommy {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            display: -moz-box;
            -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
            width: 700px;
            height: 300px;
            -moz-box-pack: center;
        }

        #mommy div {
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            -moz-box-flex: 1;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #kid1 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: green;
        }

        #kid2 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: yellow;
        }

        #kid3 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: red;
        }

        #kid4 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: orange;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<section id="mommy">
    <div id="kid1">Child 1</div>
    <div id="kid2">Child 2</div>
    <div id="kid3">Child 3</div>
    <div id="kid4">Child 4</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I went through and added the -webkit extensions, and it works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox, which I'm using.

Comment: In firefox you don't need more `-moz-` prefixes to play with flexbox. And you need to set `display: flex` to the parent (in this case `#mommy`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work better. I updated the `flexbox` rules a little.

Src: https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Welcome to my site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mommy {
            display: -webkit-box;  /* iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
            display: -ms-flexbox;  /* IE 10 */
            display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+ */
            display: flex;         /* Modern browsers */  
            border: 2px solid blue;          
            width: 700px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #mommy div {
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;   /* iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
            width: 20%;            /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
            -ms-flex: 1;           /* IE 10 */
            -webkit-flex: 1;       /* Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+ */
            flex: 1;               /* Modern browsers */  
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #kid1 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: green;
        }

        #kid2 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: yellow;
        }

        #kid3 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: red;
        }

        #kid4 {
            border: 2px solid red;
            background: orange;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<section id="mommy">
    <div id="kid1">Child 1</div>
    <div id="kid2">Child 2</div>
    <div id="kid3">Child 3</div>
    <div id="kid4">Child 4</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```